# css and js can't be visited

Tags: java, url-rewriting

When I visit my application, some `css` and `js` files cannot be visited.

In the Chrome console, it shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I cleared the cache, it still didn't work.

The files can't be found that do exist in the specified location. Say there are two files `sys.js` and `aaa.js` in the same folder, as the console says that the `sys.js` can't be found, so I tried to visit the `sys.js` in browser directly, it said that it can't be found, but the `aaa.js` is displayed correctly.

If I rename the `sys.js` file, it works. But I found that there are many other files can't be found either.

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Comment: Well obviously your URLRewrite rules are wrong. You'll have to show them if you want help solving the problem.

Comment: I didn't use the rewritten url to visit the css of js.

Comment: But if it worked before you wrote the URLRewrite rules, and stopped working afterwards, then it must be the URLRewrite that caused the problem. If you don't think URLRewrite has anything to do with the problem, why did you mention it at all?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it happens after I used the rewrite, so I'm not sure if there's underlying cause for this. Even as my understanding, it should be no  effect.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you placed the paths to the js files in a masterpage with relative paths. Try using absolute paths for aaa.js and sys.js. If you are using relative paths, let's say your page path was http://localhost/page.php?id=1 and in the rewrite format it is displayed as http://localhost/localhost/page/1, the relative paths with respect to this page are not the same anymore.

For example:
For the first format: /js/sys.js 
For the second format: ../js/sys.js

Comment: yes, I did use the absolute path for it. So my url for css is like this: http://localhost/js/xxx/sys.js.

Comment: Try placing the js link explicitly in each page rather than a control or masterpage. Also, check the link path on view source for the specific page you might be able to find out where the actual js path is pointing to.